# 2 requirements: 1) Replace multiple FOR loop with FORALL 2) use IF-THEN-ELSE condition while inserting data into table

Tags: sql, for-loop, plsql, conditional-statements, forall

My requirement is a bit different. I have two nested FOR loops that fetch data and based on certain condition it inserts sorted data into table.

**Original code below:**

```
FOR Name_1 IN First_Cursor
LOOP
  FOR Name_2 IN Second_Cursor (Name_1.Table_Field_Name)
  LOOP
    IF (Condition)
      THEN
        Prevalidation of data

        INSERT INTO <Table_Name>
          VALUES (..............................);
      ELSE
        IF (Condition)
        THEN
          Prevalidation of data

          UPDATE <Table_Name>
            WHERE .....................;

      END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

I have to convert this whole code into FORALL

I tried many code but dint succeed in any, I think the syntax itself is wrong

```
IF (Condition)
THEN
  Prevalidation of data

  FORALL Name_2 IN Second_Cursor (Name_1.Table_Field_Name) of Name_1
    INSERT INTO <Table_Name>
      VALUES (..............................);
ELSE
  IF (Condition)
  THEN
    Prevalidation of data
    FORALL Name_2 IN Second_Cursor (Name_1.Table_Field_Name) of Name_1
      UPDATE <Table_Name>
        WHERE .....................;    
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use "case" statement in sql look like :

syntax:

```
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

SQL:

```
 select column1,column2,
    ( case when col3>0 then col4 else col5 end) as 'col_name' ,
    ( case when col6='value' then col7 else col8 end) as 'col_name1' 
    from 
    table_name
    where col_name13>45
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick respose. Using CASE will be helpful if I am using FOR loop, since FORALL uses a single insert statement I am having problem executing. Here is the code wic I am trying:

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick respose. Using CASE will be helpful if I am using FOR loop, since FORALL uses a single insert statement I am having problem executing. I want to completly remove the FOR loop and use FORALL. If you could tell me with sample code then it will be very helpful.